# How to replace password in MongoDB connection string with stars - JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I want to replace password in the MongoDB connection string with stars like ***. So, instead

> mongodb://john:pwd897@some_url:234/database_name

it should be

> mongodb://john:***@some_url:234/database_name

I'm trying to use regexp to parse it:

```
^(mongodb:(?:\/{2})?)((\w+?):(\w+?)@|:?@?)(\w+?):(\d+)\/(\w+?)$
```

And looks like I need to replace $4. But I can't figure out how to do it. One of the reasons is some parts of the string can be absent, including the password itself.

Comment: Won't that just yield a bad password error?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Not sure why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edited, so it would work with passwords containing `:`:

```
var str = "mongodb://john:lal:ala@some_url:234/database_name";
str = str.replace(/\/\/([^:]+):(.*)@/,"//$1:***@");
console.log(str); // <- mongodb://john:***@some_url:234/database_name
```

To star both username and password you can use for example:

```
var str = "mongodb://john:lal:ala@some_url:234/database_name";
str = str.replace(/\/\/([^:]+):(.*)@/,"//***:***@");
console.log(str); // <- mongodb://***:***@some_url:234/database_name
```

Or just:

```
var str = "mongodb://john:lal:ala@some_url:234/database_name";
str = str.replace(/\/\/.*@/,"//***:***@");
console.log(str); // <- mongodb://***:***@some_url:234/database_name
```

Comment: Looks  like it works! Thanks! What if I want to change username with stars too? How would I change the code?

Comment: And what if the password contains `:`?

Comment: @ctwheels: edited so it would work with passwords containing `:`, thanx for pointing that out!

Comment: @FlashThunder much better +1

Comment: A password inside connection string cannot contain symbol `:` in an open form, it violates the [URL Connection String Spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). Symbol `:` must be encoded as `%3A`

Answer (score 1):

Generic [connection-string](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string) handles all such cases automatically.

Once the connection string has been parsed into an object:

```js
const {ConnectionString} = require('connection-string');

const cs = new ConnectionString('mongodb://john:pwd897@some_url:234/database_name');
```

you can generate a new connection string, optionally hashing the password:

```js
cs.toString({passwordHash: true})
//=> mongodb://john:######@some_url:234/database_name
```

or you can specify a custom symbol to be used:

```js
cs.toString({passwordHash: '*'})
//=> mongodb://john:******@some_url:234/database_name
```

See method [toString](https://github.com/vitaly-t/connection-string#tostringoptions--string).

Comment: This is a great package however I would not advise people to use it by directly adding the npm link in the package.json. The main reason is security. You will be sharing your usernames and passwords to an unknown entity. Best is to download the library as a zip, inspect that it does not send your passwords and use it locally.

Comment: @mp3por You can say that about many packages then. Everybody is using it directly, no need for paranoia here :)